# PHP preg_replace Regex Issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am fairly new to regex, but I've written a match string. I think it's pretty close, but it isn't working. I need to find URLs that match a certain pattern in a longer string.

Here are a couple of examples of URLs:

```
http://static.squarespace.com/static/j433gj93943tj9043/23rf9g4390930/4343t49t4/4g93g4390g49u0/image.png
http://static.squarespace.com/static/yy9ii93i9034/g43g34/j6j66767j6gdrdg/g4g34g34h/something.png
```

Here is my regex:

```
#^http://static.squarespace.com(a-zA-Z0-9-./)(png|jpg)$#
```

Both of those URLs should be matched, but they aren't... preg_match is returning ==== FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define (brackets) and allow for [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (plus) of your [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
^http://static.squarespace.com([a-zA-Z0-9-./]+)(png|jpg)$
```

Comment: I provided the regex, PHP requires delimiters. Add your `#` back.